# Linear span of $\{e^{-n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is dense in $L^2((0,\infty))$. Explicit expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dense-subspaces

I proved that the linear span of $\{e^{-n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is dense in $L^2((0,\infty))$ (see below).

**Question**: Given $f\in L^2((0,\infty))$, can I find "expansion coefficients" $f_n$ such that
$$f(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} f_ne^{-n x} ?$$

**Proof of density**: Using the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for locally compact Hausdorff space, the linear span of $\{e^{-n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is dense in $C_0((0,\infty))$, the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. Since $C_0((0,\infty))$ is dense in $L^2((0,\infty))$, we prove the result.

**Note**: After very nice comments, the question is simplified.

Comment: Did you try looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform?

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for comment. I know the basics of Laplace transform. Could you explain how the theory of Laplace transform helps to answer this question?

Comment: Wait a minute. It is the **linear span** of $\{ e^{-\alpha x}\}_{\alpha\ge 0}$ that is dense. Not the set itself.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, you are right. I modified the question.

Comment: The collection $E$ of functions in your problem separates points; hence the algebra it generates (polynomials in $P$) is dense in $C_0(0,\infty)$ (this is a version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for locally compact Hausdorff spaces) $C_0$ is dense in $L_p(0,\infty)$ for all $0<p<\infty$.

Comment: If $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_0^T e^{-\alpha x} \tilde f(\alpha) d\mu(\alpha)$ converges for some $x_0$ then it is analytic for $x > x_0$. So no there is often no such $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks for pointing out that. Your argument is simpler to prove that the linear span of $\{e^{-\alpha x}\}_{\alpha>0}$ is dense in $L^2((0,\infty)$. Is there way to actually write down the expansion coefficient $\tilde f(\alpha)$?

Comment: @eigenvalue: I think that even the span of  $\{f_n(x)=e^{-nx}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense on $L_2$ then you can use the methods of Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis in $L_2$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for very interesting comment. However, I cannot reconcile your statement with the fact that  linear span of $\{e^{-\alpha x}\}_{\alpha>0}$ is dense. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yes, according to the Stone-Weierstrass for locally compact Hausdorff space. By the way, how do you think of reuns's comment that if $f$ is written as $f(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \tilde f(n) e^{-nx}$, then it is likely to be analytic?

Comment: @eigenvalue $\sum_{n\ge 1} c_n e^{-nx}$ is analytic for $x > x_0$ if it converges at $x_0$ (in that case it converges in $L^2(x_0,\infty)$ norm). The $e^{-nx}$ are dense because any $L^2(0,\infty)$ function is of the form $\sum_{m \ge 1} \sum_{n=1}^{m} c_{m,n} e^{-nx}$ where the series converges in $L^2$ norm. The latter form is very different to the former.

Comment: @reuns Can't I simplify the double sum by changing the order as
$$\sum_{m\geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^m c_{m,n} e^{-nx} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sum_{m=n}^\infty c_{m,n} \right) e^{-nx}?$$
Then it really looks like $\sum_{n\geq 1} \tilde c_n e^{-nx}$, assuming $\left( \sum_{m=n}^\infty c_{m,n} \right)$ is convergent. I cannot figure out why "the latter form is very different to the former".